# Construct a bijection $i\rightarrow\sigma(i)$ such that the series $\sum a_{\sigma(i)}$ converges to $0$ when $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, permutations

I'm working on a problem which asks me to consider the series $$\sum a_k, \quad \left(a_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right)$$ and after showing that this series is convergent but not absolutely, I'm asked to construct a bijection $i\rightarrow\sigma(i)$ so that the series $$\sum a_{\sigma(i)}$$ converges to 0.

But I'm not even sure it is possible to find such a permutation. Of course one could consider the series $$-1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+...$$
but this wouldn't result in a bijection, which is where I struggle. Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Hint: If the partial sum is negative, take the next positive term. Instead of $1/8$, take $1/6$. At that point you will have partial sum $-1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{-1}{12}$. Next take $\frac{1}{8}$. The partial sum is now $-1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{+1}{24}$. Now it's positive, so grab the next available negative term, $a_3 = \frac{-1}{3}$. .. Whenever it's positive, put negative terms; whenever it's negative, put positive terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the fact that you have to construct a bijection $i\to \sigma(i)$ does not mean that you need to have a "nice" closed formula for $\sigma(i)$, but instead that all the terms appearing in your original series must also appear in the series
$$
\sum_i a_{\sigma(i)}.
$$
As you correctly noticed, the example you gave is not correct since it neglects all terms $a_k$ with $k\neq 2^n$. Instead, you can proceed as follows: order all positive terms in a decreasing way, and the absolute value of the negative terms in a decreasing way. Take the biggest term in absolute value and plug its sign (in this case it is $-1$), so that you have $\sigma(1)=1$, and $a_{\sigma(1)}=a_1=-1$. Next, label the sequence of positive terms in a decreasing way $a_{\sigma(2)}$, $a_{\sigma(3)}$, etc..., until you find $k$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k a_{\sigma(i)}>0.
$$
Then do it again with the list of negative numbers until you find $k_1$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k_1}a_{\sigma(i)}<0$, and so on. This can be done because the series is conditionally convergent, and moreover it gives a bijection $i\to \sigma(i)$ because you are not missing any term of the sequence $a_k$.